# Count non-null values from multiple columns at once without manual entry in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a SQL table with about 50 columns, the first represents unique users and the other columns represent categories which are scored 1-10.

Here is an idea of what I'm working with

| user | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 5 | null | null |
| xyz | null | 6 | null |

I am interested in counting the number of non-null values per column.

Currently, my queries are:

```
SELECT col_name, COUNT(col_name) AS count
FROM table
WHERE col_name IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a way to count non-null values for each column in one query, without having to manually enter each column name?

The desired output would be:

| column | count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 0 |

Comment: I tagged with bigquery originally but noticed that the title of my question was prepended with 'google bigquery'. I thought this would narrow the audience so I took off the tag but I've added it back again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach (no knowledge of column names is required at all - with exception of `user`)

```
select column, countif(value != 'null') nulls_count
from your_table t,
unnest(array( 
  select as struct trim(arr[offset(0)], '"') column, trim(arr[offset(1)], '"') value
  from unnest(split(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'))) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
  where trim(arr[offset(0)], '"') != 'user'
)) rec
group by column
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Can you explain please? Thanks again!

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Does that work in all SQL flavors or is that specific to big query?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do this in big-query but instead in SQL Server, however big query has the concept of unpivot as well. Basically you're trying to transpose your columns to rows and then do a simple aggregate of the columns to see how many records have data in each column. My example is below and should work in big query without much or any tweaking.

Here is the table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
  user_name char(3),
  a integer,
  b integer,
  c integer
);

INSERT INTO example(user_name, a, b, c)
VALUES('abc', 5, null, null);

INSERT INTO example(user_name, a, b, c)
VALUES('xyz', null, 6, null);

INSERT INTO example(user_name, a, b, c)
VALUES('tst', 3, 6, 1);
```

And here is the UNPIVOT I did:

```
select count(*) as amount, col 
from 
    (select user_name, a, b, c from example) e
unpivot
 (blah for col in (a, b, c)
) as unpvt
group by col
```

Here's example of the output (note, I added an extra record in the table to make sure it was working properly):
[image]

Again, the syntax may be slightly different in BigQuery but I think thould get you most of the way there.

Here's a link to my db-fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=deaa0e92a4ef1de7d4801e458652816b

Comment: Note, you still have to manually add each column name here. but I'd argue that it's a better, and easier solution than what you currently were trying.